# System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type

Tags: c#, mono, owin, appdomain

I am trying to run my windows owin self hosted service on the ubuntu with mono-complete installed.Code run perfectly on windows but when i am trying to run on ubuntu i get following exception.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Failure has occurred while loading a type.
  at LauncherServerContext.StartAction (Owin.IAppBuilder app) [0x0018b] in <5987da0293b04bdcb223a6c06c5c20de>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.ResolveApp (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext context) [0x000dc] in <f9c6a24237684643b127a582774aa6dc>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext context) [0x00059] in <f9c6a24237684643b127a582774aa6dc>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation (System.IServiceProvider services, Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options, System.Action`1[T] startup) [0x0008a] in <f9c6a24237684643b127a582774aa6dc>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions options, System.Action`1[T] startup) [0x00006] in <f9c6a24237684643b127a582774aa6dc>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start (System.String url, System.Action`1[T] startup) [0x00006] in <f9c6a24237684643b127a582774aa6dc>:0
```

note - Here i am running exe in appdomain.

please suggest.